# error while configuring resource provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code where i am trying to populate a table RESTfully by using ngResource. But when i add configuration directives i get uncaught object MINERR ASST:22
    var app = angular.module('infra', ['ngResource']);

```
app.config(function($interpolateProviderm, $resourceProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
  $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
});



app.controller("aws_load",
               ["$scope", "$resource",
               function($scope,$resource){
                var Account = $resource("aws/api/1.0/Account/:id/",
                                        {id:"@id"}, {});
                $scope.account = Account.query();


               }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on your $interpolateProvider on line 1.

```
app.config(function($interpolateProviderm, $resourceProvider) {
```

to

```
app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $resourceProvider) {
```

Comment: even after correcting the typo i seem to be getting the same error.

Comment: after looking into the error on the firebug. it is showing the following error $resourceProvider.defaults is undefined.

Comment: Have you injected/installed ngResource? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource

Comment: I'm including ngResource and this is a problem for me as well. The resource calls work fine except that the trailing slash is removed so the backend server doesn't understand what it should do. Where is 'defaults' defined on the $resourceProvider?

Comment: I solved my problem by including a beta version of angularjs and angular-resource.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the latest angularjs. The code to provide defaults for the $resourceProvider is only in more recent version of ngResource. I know for sure it got around my issue by including the 1.3.0-beta.7 version. I think it was coded 4 months ago but merged just in the last few weeks.